# Loop occurs twice within one range

Tags: python, loops

I've been struggling with this problem for a while now since loops are a bit confusing to me. Essentially, I think I got some of the more difficult stuff (for me at least) out of the way. The issue is that I need the average of 3 students per exam not 6 students per exam, which is what my current code gives.

If what I am asking isn't clear let me know and I will clear it up.

My inputs are n = 3 and m = 2.

```
def readGrade():
    grade = int(input("Enter the grade: "))
    while grade > 100 or grade < 0:
        print("Invalid Grade")
        grade = int(input("Enter the grade: "))
    return grade

def examAverage(m):
    average = 0
    for i in range(n):
        readGrade()
        average = average + readGrade()
    return (average / n)


n = int(input("Enter the number of students: "))
m = int(input("Enter the number of exams: "))


for i in range(m):
    print("The average of exam", i + 1, "is:", examAverage(m))
```

Comment: `def examAverage(m)` has an input of `m` but doesn't use it.

Comment: You're calling `readGrade()` twice in the for loop in `examAverage`.

Comment: It might be better style to collect all the exam grades into a list first. Then, loop over the list as desired. Or even better: `average = sum(grades) / n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling readGrade() two times within examAverage()

I think this is what examAverage() should be:

```
def examAverage(m):
    average = 0
    for i in range(n):
        this_grade = readGrade()
        average = average + this_grade 
    return (average / n)
```

Comment: Since m is the input parameter into examAverage shouldn't you use it rather than n in the for loop and in computing the average?

Comment: Do you mind explaining what you mean by calling readGrade() twice? Your solution did resolve my issue but I'm not completely understanding why.

Comment: Since you call `readGrade()` twice in the function, you'd be inputting twice as many values for the same number of students, giving you incorrect averages.

Comment: This is where the root of your problem becomes evident. If `n=3` you'd be inputting `n*2=6` values instead.